# Is there a way to edit a pdf with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I would need to edit a pdf at runtime in C#.NET. Is this possible? Like copying things in the pdf, editing textfields, ...?

Comment: +1; I was just wondering if this was possible this morning and I had just assumed that it was too difficult or costly and promptly forgot about this. Thanks for asking it...

Comment: You can edit it easily with BinaryReader and BinaryWriter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [iTextSHARP](http://itextpdf.com/). It's a .NET library for manipulating PDFs.

Comment: Worth noting that iTextSharp is licensed under AGPL, which means that technically all of your source code for the project has to be published publicly. If you want a closed environment, you'd be obligated to purchase a commercial license.

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely possible, but not with what is built-in to .NET (unless you are a PDF format guru and can roll your own).  I've mostly used [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) for manipulating PDFs, but there are a lot of toolkits out there.  Personally, I think Aspose is a little rough around the edges but not moreso than other kits.

Answer (score 3):

Well there's iTextSharp : http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ with which you can write pdf files, but I don't think it has editing (reading pdf) capabilities, or they will be limited.
I've never found a way to edit PDF's, unless you buy some third party tool ...

Answer (score 2):

[Look at this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

> iText# (iTextSharp) is a port of the iText open source java library for PDF generation written entirely in C# for the .NET platform.

Comment: It's probably better if the link text gives a hint about what you're linking to.

Comment: @Odrade, done! (15chars)

Answer (score 2):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) may be used to edit PDF files. You can fill forms, import and export forms data, extract text, append documents and so on. Please take a look at [samples for the library](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples).

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, have a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Answer (score 1):

ITextSharp is good for adding things to a PDF.

These PDF components are also pretty good: [www.tallcomponents.com](http://www.tallcomponents.com)