# Editing areas of a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to edit a pdf with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923546/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-pdf-with-c)

We have a requirement to edit parts of a PDF in C#.  Are there any libraries available to do this?

I would assume that the PDF created will have to have areas defined as editable - but I don't even know how they would be defined?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Itextsharp:

> iText# (iTextSharp) is a port of the iText open source java library
>   for PDF generation written entirely in C# for the .NET platform.

Check this tutorials:

[Tutorials on creating PDF files using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18040/Tutorials-on-creating-PDF-files-using-C-2-0)

[ItextSharp tutorial](http://blog.rubypdf.com/itextsharp/tutorial01/)

**EDIT:** How to fill forms with Itextsharp:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23112/Fill-in-PDF-Form-Fields-using-the-Open-Source-iTex

Comment: But I don't want to *create* a PDF - I just want to be able to edit parts of it - does ITextSharp do that?

Comment: I edit the post, check the last link

Comment: You can do almost everything with pdf. Create editable forms, fill the forms. etc