# Add Text in Docusign Completed Document and Send to Other user- C#-RestAPI

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I need to Add a Text at the end of the Document, after completing the Signature ceremony. I retrieved the completed document using REST API,  but how can i add a new Text at the end of the Retrieved Document and Send it as a new Envelope using RestAPI.

Comment: sounds like you want to add the text programmatically? ?

Comment: Yes, and want to send it to a new Signer.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app does that help?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. It is different. It is simply get a PDF and send. But my issue i need to add a new Text into that PDF(envelope completed document) which is provided from Docusign

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923546/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-pdf-with-c

Comment: This is using ITextSharp, i dont have that tool and i am not supposed to use that in my code.

Comment: You can add text by adding a DS text tab on the document, but how you want to add the text tab on the document, either by X/Y position or it has any anchor string available in the retrieved document?

Comment: I have a anchor string can use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an API call to the DocuSign eSignature API to add a text tab like Amit suggested.
You can see the information about this endpoint here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create

You basically make a :

```
POST /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```

Note you must know the envelopeId and recipientId for the specific recipient you choose. And then the body of you call specify information about the tab. it's all in the link above.