# Tools for filling pdf forms in browser

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am working on an application that allows a user to upload a pdf (created in Adobe) that contains fields. I want to allow the user to be able to populate these fields with their company data. The workaround I have right now is to display the PDF in the browser, along with a toolbar that displays the fields present on the pdf and an input box for them to fill out. What I want to get to is allowing them to actually click on the fields in the pdf, and fill them out this way. I would need to have events fired for whenever they fill out a field so that I can updated field values on the backend (the data they are inputting is not raw, it is actually mapped to a object given when I generate the final pdf). Are there any tools available that would allow me to display a pdf with its field, and have events surrounding interactions with those fields?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923546/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-pdf-with-c

Comment: @devlincarnate I am already using PyPDF2 in a django app to populate my PDF at runtime. I want the user to assign values to fields within the PDF but those values won't directly manipulate the pdf they are working on. Instead those values are going to be stored, and then when the pdf is requested to be generated I am going to populate the fields using PyPdf2.